# Autolayout subview add issue in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I am trying to add a subview into fullscreen parent view, but it does not show up in full parent view. If I don't init or don't set it inside frame, it does not show up
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
You will find something helpful
**Just simply add this UIView extension**

```
extension UIView {
    func fillInSuperView(inset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero)  {
            self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.superview?.leadingAnchor)!, constant: inset.left).isActive = true;
            self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.superview?.trailingAnchor)!, constant: -inset.right).isActive = true
            self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.superview?.topAnchor)!, constant: inset.top).isActive = true
            self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.superview?.bottomAnchor)!, constant: -inset.bottom).isActive = true
        }
}
```

Calling of this function

```
YourView.fillInSuperView(inset: UIEdgeInsets.zero)
```

You can set padding from the the superView by setting insets

Answer (score 0):

change 
v1 width and height 
to parent width and height 
like

```
let v1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: view.bounds.size.width, height: view.bounds.size.height))
```

this may work

Comment: i thought autolayout should auto update width height with constraints, if i need to set width, height, then what is meaning of autolayout here ?

Answer (score 0):

Change v1 frame layout to full-screen layout. The height and width would be full-screen height and width. You can update frame size by using this

```
let v1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))
```

By using this no need to use `Autolayout` constraints.

Comment: you are not understand my question, sorry. my question is why subview not show fullscreen parent view with constraint

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you have specified fix width and height for v1

```
 i.e. let v1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 100, height: 50))
```

instead try this

```
let v1 = UIView()
// this will take frame(x, y, width, height) from superview
v1.frame = view.frame
```

Comment: no this, no relate to the view, whatever size you set, autolayout still apply the constraint

Comment: hmm, but this new v1 view will grab the same frame like its superview, and will fit in.

Comment: try this v1.frame = view.bounds (here view is your superview)

Comment: what is want is when super view change, subview also autolayout with the constraints, what frame you set for the v1 doesn't important

Answer (score 0):

Change v1 frame size as full view by using this

```
let v1 = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

This will work.

Comment: i dont want, just want v1 full screen superview when superview resize, not fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
let v1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
    v1.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    v1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(v1)

    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v1]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["v1" : v1]))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v1]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["v1" : v1]))
```

Comment: this product same effect in playground.

Comment: Are you working with playground ?
I added this code for iOS you can see effect of this code in UI of simulator and device.

Comment: i just tell you the constraint you added and the new anchor constraint did same effect, yes, i tested on playground,

Comment: Then something other issue you have.
Because i have tested it in iOS simulator and it is working fine.